# Scala Regex Positive and Negative Look Behind at the same time

Tags: regex, scala

I have an input string like this

```
val input = """["abc:def&ghi:jkl"]"""
```

I want to extract `abc` and `ghi` So I wrote this regex which works

```
val regex = """(?<=["&])(\w+)(?=[:])""".r
regex.findAllIn(input).foreach(println)
```

So basically I have a look ahead for `:` and a look behind for either `"` or `&`.

So far so good. But now I have an input like this

```
val input = """["abc:de_&_f:xyz&ghi:jkl"]"""
```

it matches

```
abc
_f
ghi
```

I want to change the logic of my regex to say.

Match a `\w+` when look ahead is true for `:` and look behind is true for `&` and false for `_&_`

So I want to use the positive and negative look behind at the same time. How do I do that?

Comment: What's your expected result for second input?

Comment: How about a non-regex solution? 1) first string: `substring(0, index_of_first_colon)`. 2) second string: `substring(index_of_ampersand, index_of_next_colon)`. Applying a filter to the result should also be easy.

Comment: The expected output is the same as the first oneput

Comment: The question is about regexes.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch sure. That's why I posted a comment. Seems a split on `:` with some simple filtering can easily produce the same results though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead inside the lookbehind expression in your regex as:

```
(?<=(?:(?<!_)&(?!_)|"))\w+(?=:)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pf4LdU/2)

Here we are using an alternation in the lookbehind condition which is:

- `(?<!_)&(?!_)|"`: Match `&` if it is not preceded and followed by `_`
- `|`: OR
- `"` match `"`

---

For your case this shorter regex may also work:

```
(?<=["&])(?<!_&)\w+(?=:)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Pf4LdU/1)

`(?<!_&)` will skip the match if `\w+` is preceded by `_&`.

Answer (score 2):

You could update your pattern to not match the underscore in `\w` first using a negated character class `[^\W_]\w*`

As you want a single match only, you can omit the capturing group `()` and the square brackets in `[:]` can be omitted.

```
(?<=["&])[^\W_]\w*(?=:)
```

- `(?<=["&])` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is `"` or `&`
- `[^\W_]` Match a word char except `_`
- `\w*` Match 0+ word chars
- `(?=:)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0mVMz/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/tt4t9V)

Comment: But this won't work for input `val input = "a_bc:def"`. We have to skip only when we encounter `_&_` not otherwise.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/KqDNX6/1

Comment: while this works. my question was can we do a AND between a positive and negative lookbehind?